# how to transfer data between two activities

Tags: java, android

I have an arraylist and each index also has an arraylist. Each index is listed in listview. how can I pass the data between two activities? I tried thses code but when I clicked the listview, it crashed.

on my mainAcitivity

```
FuelView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intents = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditEntry.class);
        String i = String.valueOf(position);
        intents.putExtra(KEY, i);
        startActivity(intents);`
     }
}
```

on my secondActivity

```
 loadFromFile();
    Intent intents = getIntent();
    final int index = Integer.valueOf(intents.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY));
    findEntry(index);
```

on findEntry function

```
Entrylist Entrylist = Entrylists.get(index);

    EditText new_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
    new_date.setText(Entrylist.getDate().toString());
    EditText new_station = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.station);
    new_station.setText(Entrylist.getStation().toString());
    EditText new_odometer= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.odometer);
    new_odometer.setText(Entrylist.getOdometer().toString());
    EditText new_grade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fuel_grade);
    new_grade.setText(Entrylist.getGrade().toString());
    EditText new_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fuel_amount);
    new_amount.setText(Entrylist.getAmount().toString());
    EditText new_cost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unit_cost);
    new_cost.setText(Entrylist.getCost().toString());

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    save.setText("Save");
```

Here is the error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.larin.aolin1_fueltrack/com.example.larin.aolin1_fueltrack.EditEntry}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
                                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:355)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:490)
                                                                                    at com.example.larin.aolin1_fueltrack.EditEntry.onCreate(EditEntry.java:41)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error trace.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to parse the index using?

```
final int index = Integer.parseInt(intents.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY));
```

Also, you could send int values through intent:

```
intent.putExtra(KEY, position);      // put int value to intent
getIntent.getIntExtra(KEY, -1);      // get int value where -1 is the default value
```

Comment: Very strange... What about getIntent().getExtras()? is this null? Or getIntent().getExtras().getString(MainActivity.KEY)?

Comment: shall I put these in mainActivity of secondActivity? If I comment these two link, I am able to get access to secondActivity.//final int index = Integer.valueOf(intents.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY));
    findEntry(index);//

Comment: the problem is here "getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY)" since you get a "null" value instead of valid string (ex: "2"). There are 2 main reasons: 1. the KEY from first activity is not the same with the KEY from second activity, 2. type is not the same (Ex: you add int value to the intent in the first activity, then you try to get String value in the second activity). In you case I really don't know where the problem is. I've just tested your code and it works for me.